# JUnitCore: Does it hit breakpoint

Tags: java, junit

I am currently learning how to use JUnitCore to run some tests with my application, I think I have it all working fine as it seems to move through the debugger without any problems but I have yet to get my test to print anything to the console `System.out.println(...)`

```
Result results= JUnitCore.runClasses(test.class);
System.out.println(results.getRunCount());
```

When I add a breakpoint to the first line it hits it, but I have another breakpoint inside `test.class` that when I move to the next breakpoint it never hits, it also wont let me step into the `JUnitCore.runClasses(test.class);` call either... But it does return 1 for `results.getRunCount()`

Does anyone know if this is working for me and you are not able to hit breakpoints inside tests this way or is there a problem with `JUnitCore.runClasses(test.class)`?

Answer (score 0):

I JUnitCore.runClasses are not supposed to print out any message, it will just run the tests.

You will need to add code that will handle any failure and therefore produces some print out.